# [SOLVED]Ltspice: Move the schematics

Tags: ltspice

How do I move the schematic / page in ltspice. I meant if I have a schematic, and I want to move (move in the page). Like the "keep right press the right click and move" in Altium.

If I want to move, I should zoom.

Thank you

Comment: Just click hold and move the canvas? I don't understand your problem, do you want to put all the elements at a different position? that doesnt' make much sense, there is no absolute spot on the canvas.

Comment: What does the manual say about this?

Comment: Thank you. I already did it. I guess that's a bug in my download. I'll try to reinstall it then. I thought the error is comming from me.

Comment: Which manual are you talking about?

Comment: No need to change the title to indicate "Solved". Just accept an answer and the system will indicate the question is solved.

Comment: Hit space key to fit all

Answer (score 4):

You pan in LTSpice by left-clicking the canvas (not on the schematic elements themselves, but on the background behind them) and dragging it around.

Comment: Mind blown. I've been zooming out and back in (and then out and back in because the way zooms center is ass-backwards) for years.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I finally reinstall LTspice, that's work well now. Thanks all

Comment: @ThePhoton I hear you, I did that for ages before stumbling across the control by accident

Comment: @Tack Glad to hear you got it sorted! If this answer helped, consider marking it as "Accepted" for future readers =)